# Incompatible types when passing method in another class

Tags: java, incompatibletypeerror

I'm getting incompatible type error when I use these methods from another class, I'm supposed to return an array of all the cars whose average horsepower for a given year is within the range specified.

here is my methods from the other class which returns arraylist:

```
public ArrayList<Lamborghini> getCarsFromThisYear(int year){
    ArrayList<Lamborghini> fromYear = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>();

    for( Lamborghini c : inventory){
        if(c.getModelYear() == year){
            fromYear.add(c);
        }
    }

    if( fromYear.size() == ZERO){
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return fromYear;
}

public Lamborghini[] getCarsWithHorsepowerRange(double lowHP, double highHP){
    int matches = ZERO;

    for (Lamborghini c : inventory){
        if(c.getHorsepower() >= lowHP && c.getHorsepower() <= highHP){
            matches++;
        }
    }
    Lamborghini[] horsepower = new Lamborghini[matches];
    int indexInArray = ZERO;
    for (Lamborghini c : inventory){
        if(c.getHorsepower() >= lowHP && c.getHorsepower() <= highHP){
            horsepower[indexInArray] = c;
            indexInArray++;
        }
    }
    return horsepower;
}
```

and here is what im working on, i'm getting error where it calls :
c.getCarsFromThisYear(modelYear) and (c.getCarsWithHorsepowerRange(lowHP, highHP)

```
public LamborghiniCarLot[] getAllCarLotsWithAverageHorsepowerInRangeForYear(int modelYear, double lowHP, double highHP){
    int matches = ZERO;

    for(LamborghiniCarLot c : carLots){
        if (c.getCarsFromThisYear(modelYear)){
            if(c.getCarsWithHorsepowerRange(lowHP, highHP)){
                matches++;
            }
        }
    }

    LamborghiniCarLot[] search = new LamborghiniCarLot[matches];
    int index = ZERO;

    for(LamborghiniCarLot c : carLots){
        search[index] = c;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Give us a stack trace so we can see what the error is and where.

Comment: You're missing a return statement in `getAllCarLotsWithAverageHorsepowerInRangeForYear`

Comment: @RobertMoskal sry, im new to prgramming, i have no idea how to do that

Comment: @swingMan that is because its not finished yet, my problem is at first for each loop when i use c.getCarsFromThisYear(ModelYear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of issues with the following method:

```
  public ArrayList<Lamborghini> getCarsFromThisYear(int year){
    ArrayList<Lamborghini> fromYear = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>();

    for( Lamborghini c : inventory){
        if(c.getModelYear() == year){
            fromYear.add(c);
        }
    }

    if( fromYear.size() == ZERO){
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return fromYear;
  }
```

- Return `List<Lamborghini>` instead of `ArrayList<Lamborghini>`
- When the size of **fromYear** list "ZERO" just return the array list you have instantiated in the second line of the method. Or change the `ArrayList<>()` to `ArrayList<Laborghini>` in your `if` statement.

Here is a what I would suggest:

```
public List<Lamborghini> getCarsFromThisYear(int year){
    List<Lamborghini> fromYear = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>();

    for( Lamborghini c : inventory){
        if(c.getModelYear() == year){
            fromYear.add(c);
        }
    }

    return fromYear;
  }
```

The other issue is that in `if (c.getCarsFromThisYear(modelYear))`. The method returns `List<Lamborghini>` but the if statement expecting `boolean` value.

Comment: thank you, doesn't really answer my question but it did help with some other things

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `if (c.getCarsFromThisYear(modelYear))`?

Comment: im trying to use that method to get cars thats from the year searched